# window.clearInterval is not working?

Tags: javascript, toggle, intervals

I'm using JS to animate two images by having them toggle on and off. I have an initial image which, when the animation is turned on, appears on the screen and stays on. The second image, which has a higher z value, is then set to toggle on and off every 1 second in the same location as the first image, so it appears as if the two are alternating.

I'm using window.setInterval to make the second image blink, but when I need to turn the animation off (and I'm removing both images from the screen), my window.clearInterval is not "working" The first image will be gone, but the second one keeps blinking on and off every second.

Code:

```
function notebookNotification(setting)
{
    $("#lightNotificationContainer").show();
    var notificationAnimation = window.setInterval('$("#darkNotificationContainer").toggle()', 1000);
    if(setting == 0)
    {
        window.clearInterval(notificationAnimation);
        $("#lightNotificationContainer").hide();
        $("#darkNotificationContainer").hide();
    }
}
```

Anyone see why it isn't working?

Comment: Have you got a test case?  I'm guessing it has to do with the fact that notificationAnimation has been declared within the scope of the notebookNotification function, so you can't reference that variable again once the function has run once.  Try storing the interval in a global variable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reading between the lines, I think what you're saying is this:

1. You execute `notebookNotification(1);` and the animation starts
2. You execute `notebookNotification(0);` and the animation does **not** stop.

My guess is that you want `notebookNotification(0)` to disable the flashing.

In order to do that, you need to rework this function considerably. You need to store the `intervalID` that comes from `setInterval` in a variable that survives outside of the scope of this function and can be used for `clearInterval` on subsequent calls to this function.

For example:

```
var intervalID;
function notebookNotification(setting)
{
    if(setting == 0)
    {
        if(intervalID) {
            window.clearInterval(intervalID);
            intervalID = null;
        }
        $("#lightNotificationContainer").hide();
        $("#darkNotificationContainer").hide();
    }
    else
    {
        $("#lightNotificationContainer").show();
        if(!intervalID) {
            intervalID = window.setInterval('$("#darkNotificationContainer").toggle()', 1000);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ahh, it works like a charm now. I see that I needed to store my interval outside the function; I thought since it was declared inside, it would still be in the scope blah blah blah. Thank you for your help!!!

Comment: Actually, *because* you declare it inside, it goes out of scope when the function ends. There may be better ways to store this intervalID without polluting the global namespace (maybe, using jQuery.data), but that code is a quick and dirty version

Answer (score 2):

Here, try this:

http://jsfiddle.net/WGxmy/

Saving the interval to a global variable -- not one inside a function -- lets you clear it later.

Comment: Someone beat you to the punch, but yes, that was my problem, not having it as a global variable. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1):

```
var keepflashing = true;
var isShowing = true;
function notebookNotification()
{
    if(!isShowing)
        $("#lightNotificationContainer").show();
    else
        $("#lightNotificationContainer").show();

    isShowing = !isShowing;

    if(keepflashing)
      setTimeout( function(){  notebookNotification(setting);  },100);
    else
    {
        $("#lightNotificationContainer").hide();
        $("#darkNotificationContainer").hide();
    }
}
```

Comment: I thought about doing this function recursively. Looks like this way would work too

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can avoid calling  *clearInterval()* generally?

```
function notebookNotification(setting)
{
    if(setting == 0)
    {
        $("#lightNotificationContainer").hide();
        $("#darkNotificationContainer").hide();
    }
    else
    {
        $("#lightNotificationContainer").show();
        window.setInterval('$("#darkNotificationContainer").toggle()', 1000);
    }
}
```

Comment: If I don't clear the interval, it will keep toggling the darkNotificationContainer on and off, even if I "hide" it. Hiding it only does it once, while the interval will continue to toggle, thus turning it back on... and off... and on... etc.

Comment: Do you call notebookNotification() more than once?

Comment: Yes. The question has been answered though, but thank you for your time!!